# Can I write a generic function to modify UI elements across all of my view controllers?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I would like to know if there is a way where I can write a generic function that can be stored in something like a Utility class that will modify UI elements?

In other words, right now I'm changing the color of certain UI elements programmatically like so:

```
headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red green:green blue:blue alpha:1.0];

//Where red, green and blue are variables that are derived from another function 
//that converts Hex to RGB and 'headerLabel' is a UILabel with a connected IBOutlet
```

This same procedure happens in every View Controller, so I was wondering if there is a way to make this a generic function?

In Java / the Android SDK, I can pass the context of the class and do the rest from there.

Thank you in advance!!

**EDIT:**

To re-phrase the question a little, I would like to have the `headerLabel.textColor=` function, and other methods like `headerLabel.text = @"foo"` in that generic class, not necessarily just the color function.

Comment: You want to have `HEX` to `UIColor` function in all of your files?

Comment: I was hoping to have the `headerLabel.textColor=` in the global class, not necessarily the color function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes , its possible by creating a global file to store all your colors ,preferences like navbar,title etc,

create a class like gconstants , then store all your string here in h/m files

```
 extern NSString *const APP_TITLE;

 @interface UIColor (APP)
+(UIColor *) APP_NAV_COLOR;
 @end
```

in .m file

```
 NSString *const APP_TITLE = @"APP Name";

@implementation UIColor (APP)

+(UIColor *) APP_NAV_COLOR { return [UIColor colorWithRed:00/256.0 green:111/256.0    
 blue:59/256.0 alpha:1.0]; }
```

@end

and in any controller declare the header file

```
 self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor APP_NAV_COLOR];

headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor APP_NAV_COLOR];

self.title = APP_TITLE
```

Comment: Thank you for your post.  However, I am looking for a way to have everything, the color function and the `headerLabel.textColor =`, stored in a global class.  Any ideas?

Comment: i ended up just creating a bunch of functions for each UI element and then in the view controller just list out the elements and point the UIColor to those utility functions

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have HEX->UICOLOR in all of your files, put this:

```
#define UIColorFromHEX(hexValue) [UIColor colorWithRed:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16))/255.0 green:((float)((hexValue & 0xFF00) >> 8))/255.0 blue:((float)(hexValue & 0xFF))/255.0 alpha:1.0]
```

in your `Prefix.pch` file. Then, in every file, you can change colors via

```
something.color = UIColorFromHEX(0xCCCCCC);
```

---

You can define everything via `#define` macro. If you want to define `headerLabel.textColor`, use

```
#define setHeaderLabelColor headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor ...]
```

Comment: this is what i was looking for! .. I am going to test it out to confirm.  thank you

Comment: Looks like I can only use this for simple, 1 line functions.  I need it for something like 50+ lines

Comment: No, you can put all 50 lines there: `#define something line1; line2; line3; line4; line5`

Comment: How could I subclass this?  I see how you can add more lines now, it's just a little hard to read in the code if I crunch all those lines together

Comment: FWIW, in `#define` macros, lines can have a continuation character, \, so the next line is seen as belonging to the macro. Can't show this properly in a comment, example: `#define SWAP(a, b)  {                   \
                        a ^= b;         \
                        b ^= a;         \ 
                        a ^= b;         \
                    } `. Each of the \ is at the end of a line, so the macro contains 5 lines in total.

Comment: But I would recommend to put this in a real method in a real Utility class. The method can be a class method, so you call it with `something.color = [ViewUtilities colorFromHex: $CCCCDD]` or similar.